# Trying to calculate annual cycle

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I'm trying to take 5 years of data from a netcdf file for a variable and create an annual cycle. So take all 5 Jans and average them, take all 5 Febs and average them, etc, and plot on a line graph. I'm just starting the code (I want to get this to work before I move on) and am getting the following error message of: In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

My question is, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance. I'm a newbie, so I know this may be a simple question.

```
ncid = netcdf.open('example.nc','NC_NOWRITE');
PS1 = netcdf.getVar(ncid,netcdf.inqVarID(ncid, 'ps'), 'single');

for i = 1:12
    MonthlyPS1(i) = PS1(month==i);        
end
```

That *should* dump data into bins for each month, where I can later calculate the average.

Comment: What returns `size(PS1)`? What returns `size(month)`?

Comment: Lauren: @CST-Link asked a follow-up question 9 minutes after you asked your question. Now it's been an hour and you still haven't responded. For your information: the question is unanswerable as it stands. I will advise you to make it a general rule to stick around after asking a question. People are here for one reason only: Help others.  If you, being the one asking the question, don't give any response, people will likely downvote the question, and vote to close it. Just a heads-up! You will drive away those willing to help!

Comment: Thanks, @RobertP. - I'm a new user. I seriously appreciate the advice.

Comment: Thanks @CST-Link for your response. size(PS1) returns 1152 720 60. size(month) returns 2 60.

Comment: @Lauren5 1) If I understand correctly, the value 60 that keeps appearing in the datasets size is an index of month, i.e. 1 = 1st month of the first year, 2 = 2nd month of the first year, ... 13 = 1st month of the  2nd year, ... 60 = 12th month of the 5th year. Is this correct? 2) What is stored in the `month` variable? I see is indexed by 2 indices (because the size is [2,60]) where the last must be the month if assertion 1) is correct. What means the first index? 3) I'll get back with more questions, my number of chars per comment runs out of digits... :-)

Comment: @CST-Link 1) You are correct. 2) It's "days since 1976-01-01 00:00:00", which I know sounds odd because the dataset I pulled for for Jan 1994- Dec 1998. I pulled monthly data, so each number is 30 or 31 days apart from the previous, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Lauren5 4) The expected monthly average for `PS1` is an array of size [1152, 720, 12]? or it needs to be further processed?

Comment: @CST-Link 4) Yes, I believe you are correct.

Comment: @CST-Link I think you are asking me if the month variable is [2,60], what does the the first index mean. I'm not sure how to find that. A ncdisp says the month variable is a 60x1, if that helps anything.

Comment: @Lauren5 I posted some code. Counld you please verify if it's what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to write a solution, but I'm no sure it is what you need (there's a certain amount of guessing related to my answer).

Also I will not write it in Matlab-idiomatic code, but rather explicit loops and calculations; like this you may see easier if it's what you want or not:

```
% allocate space for monthly mean values
PS1_mean = zeros(size(PS1,1), size(PS1,2), 12)

for d = 1:size(PS1,3)
    % calculate the month for date d
    m = mod(d, 12);
    if m == 0
        m = 12;
    end;

    % cumulate the data
    PS1_mean(:, :, m) = PS1_mean(:, :, m) + PS1(:, :, d);
end;

% calculate the mean value 
% (this might be tricky for incomplete years)
n_years = fix(size(PS1,3) / 12);
PS1_mean = PS1_mean / n_years;
```

To plot a "slice" of data for e.g. March, you may try:

```
mesh(PS1_mean(:,:,3));
```

Again, I hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If `PS1` is a 5-by-12 array of real numbers, then:

```
MonthlyPS1 = mean(PS1);
```

If `PS1` is a 12-by-5 array of real numbers, then:

```
MonthlyPS1 = mean(PS1, 2);
```

If PS1 is a 60-by-1 array of real numbers, then:

```
MonthlyPS1 = mean(reshape(PS1, 12, 5), 2);
```

If `PS1` is not an array of real numbers, you need to explain what `PS1` is, as requested by CST-Link. Also, it is not clear what the variable `month` is.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I see what you're doing and it will be useful later in my code. You're right, I needed to supply more information as requested by CST-Link. But I really do appreciate your time.